# How to move files from subdirectory to directory above parent directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to move all of the files and subdirectories from /XBLA/gameName/gameID/000D0000/ to /XBLA/gameName/ I have searched and tried the methods I've found but have not been able to make them work. I also need to be able to do this for all the different /gameName directories inside /XBLA/. Below is the code I have tried that does not work at all. I have tried some other combinations, but I can't remember them at the moment.

```
          static void MoveFiles()
                {
                string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
                string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
                List<string> directoryName = Directory.GetFiles(unpackedPath, "000D0000", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                List<string> destinationDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(unpackedPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
                List<string> gameFiles = Directory.GetFiles(unpackedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                foreach (string file in gameFiles)
                    {
                        File.Move(gameFiles.ToString(), destinationDirectory.ToString());                
                    }
                
                }
```

Comment: destinationDirectory is a List, not a string, so destinationDirectory.ToString() will not give you the directory path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DirectoryInfo` class can be helpful here. You can create one based on a string that represents the path, and then easily move directories and files.

Here's an example, but it would need some additional error handling for occasions where the source or destination directory don't exist:

```
public static void MoveFilesUpTwoDirectories(string sourceDir)
{
    var source = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);
    var dest = source.Parent.Parent;

    foreach(var subDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        subDir.MoveTo(Path.Combine(dest.FullName, subDir.Name));
    }

    foreach(var file in source.GetFiles())
    {
        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(dest.FullName, file.Name));
    }
}
```

In use it would simply be:

```
string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string unpackedPath = Path.Combine(homePath, @"XBLA_Unpacked\000D0000");
MoveFilesUpTwoDirectories(unpackedPath);
```

Comment: So what this program does in unrar xbox live arcade archives and make the readable by a program called emulation station desktop edition, so I cant directly put in the gameName or id. Would a for loop and getDirectory work to make this work for a whole folder of different XBLA archives?

Comment: I don't see why not, it just needs a string path as input. Doesn't matter how you get it.

Comment: awesome, im playing around with it now. With the above code it errored out saying it couldn't find the whole path, but i feel like this is very close lol

Comment: Post another question if you get stuck. I can see that there might be some issues if folders or files have the same name and we're trying to dump them all in the same parent directory, but something like this should work:

Comment: `var homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);var xblaDir = Path.Combine(homePath, "XBLA");foreach (var gameName in Directory.GetDirectories(xblaDir)) foreach (var gameId in Directory.GetDirectories(gameName)) MoveFilesUpTwoDirectories(gameId);`

Comment: Yeah this brings the 000D0000 folder to where I need all the files to be, so its definitely close. I will keep tinkering. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure. What part isn't working?

Comment: I need the files and folders inside 000D0000 to be inside gameName. Currently it moves that whole folder to gameName